# DNN 7.02.02 Installed Skins Not Appearing

Tags: dotnetnuke, skin

I am in the process of testing a skin that is being developed by my work. I am fairly noobish when it comes to DNN. I am running everything locally (dnndev.me).
The problem is that I install the skin + container package and apparently everything is fine. No errors or warnings at all during the install. When I go to Admin -> Appearance and change the site skin it is not listed in any of the drop downs. I tried installing another skin (Metro7) and it worked perfectly fine.
Some other things I have done:

- Uninstalled and re-installed the skin
- Repaired install
- Emptied Cache
- Restarted Application
- Tried solutions found here: http://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/forumid/109/postid/487523/scope/posts http://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/forumid/109/postid/463984/scope/posts
- Watched official and third party skin tutorials and videos

So far nothing has worked. If anyone can provide a solution that would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by checking to see where the Skin files are installed. Are they in /portals/_default/skins/SKINNAME

or are they mistakenly in /desktopmodules/SkinName

If the latter, that is the wrong location for skins.